# realization about performance filesystems and Inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

I have a hard drive

[image]

when i execute "mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb" filesystem makes

[image]

if i have a file and it takes full of capacity of that hard drive

1-only one Inode i use for this file?

2-other Inodes waste capacity?
and is this the reason some filesystems are good for large files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you have 1 file then you are using 1 inode (well, there's also a couple of extra inodes used by default for other purposes just because of the way the filesystem works; e.g. the base directory and `lost+found` need inodes).

The other inodes *are* wasted... but they don't necessarily use that much space.  You may be able to gain a few Mbyte...

When you make a filesystem you should consider what type of usage you're going to put on there.  If it's a lot of small files then you might want to increase the number of inodes.  If it's a small number of large files then you might want to decrease the number of inodes.  This can be specified, for example, with the `-i` flag.

Comment: there is not limitation for how many sectors allocate for an Inode,right?

Comment: Maximum filesize is a limitation of block size.  With a 2K block size (default value) you can create a file up to 256Gbyte :-)

Comment: thank you so much but  without thinking about wasted inodes in this case 80 MB , what are other reasons?

Comment: oh,can we say the main different between filesystems is block size?